# Rails 3.1 cocoon gem for nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems, nested, cocoon-gem

I'm actually trying cocoon gem(by nathanvda) along with simple_form gem to dynamically add and remove fields on a form .I don't understand why the nested form doen't show up on my forms.Here's the code.(I'm newbie of course).Please can I have some help.

**menu/_form.html.erb**

> <%= simple_form_for @menu do |f| %>
>
> ```
>      <%= f.input :name %>
>     <%= f.input :price %>
>
>    <%= f.simple_fields_for :drinks do |drink| %>
>        =render "drink_fields", :f => drink.links %> 
>       <%= link_to_add_association "Add drink"%>
>      <%end%> 
>
>      <%= f.button :submit %> 
>         <%end%>
> ```

**menu/_drink_fields.html.erb**

> .nested-fields
>         <%= f.input :name %>
>          <%= link_to_remove_association "remove drink", f  %>

**these are the models**

```
class Drinks < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :menu
end

class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :drinks_attributes  

  has_many :drinks, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :drinks

end
```

**in assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require cocoon
```

**in layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :cocoon %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested form is wrong, you are mixing haml and erb. If you have no personal preference yet, I would recommend using haml, I find it much easier and cleaner than erb.

All that aside, your `menu/_drink_fields.html.erb` should look as follows:

```
<div class='nested-fields'> 
  <%= f.input :name %> 
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove drink", f %>
</div>
```

Also, inside your `menu/_form.html.erb` you should write the following:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :drinks do |drink| %>
   <%= render "drink_fields", f: drink %> 
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_association "Add drink", f, :drinks %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've change the code but the problem remain almost the same on the  menu/_form.html.erb I see the "add drink" link.But when i press it anything happens at all.I really don't understand what's not working(ps: I want to solve the problem with html.erb, instead of swiching to haml)

Comment: Are you using jquery? Can you check inside your browser console what javascript errors you are getting?

Comment: I will continue to search why cocoon is not working in my project.But for the moment I just want to be productive and progress on learning rails.Thanks for you support nathanvda.

Comment: i agree that haml is better than erb, but just how do you do inline snippets in haml?

Comment: @gwho ask a separate question for this, with an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the head ups nathanvda.I finally find a gem to handle nested fields, Here is the link: https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields.

Comment: that looks really awesome, although I don't thing they intend to make it compatible with rails 4, and I would like to migrate my app to rails 4 at some time.

Have you found anything that works nicely and on rails 4?